# How do I change recyclerView item background color to shaded white background?

Tags: android

[image]

If we see the above image in 3rd row we can see white shaded rating bar, I want this same thing in one of my app, Any ideas/best ways to do it.
I am populating above rating list on RecyclerView list and I am populating the items using RecyclerView adapter.

Comment: `setAlpha()` of the `View` class will do the trick. Just use a value below 1, e.g.: 0,6

Comment: set alpha in item xml file like  android:alpha="0.5" .

Comment: I can't set that in .xml I have to do dynamically

Comment: @LucaNicoletti your solution is working, Can you put your answer below that will help others

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the alpha channel of the views! Use the `setAlpha()` method of the `View` class to achieve this! Use `setAlpha()` with a value below 1, e.g.: 0.66.

Comment: Thanks Luca Nicoletti

Answer (score 3):

try to reduce the opacity of your recycler item inside the adapter,
get the inflating positions of list/recyclerview if position is greater than 3 then apply `rowView.setAlpha(0.6f);`...for position 4 change alpha `tvText.setAlpha(0.8f);` similarly for topviews change the aplha `tvText.setAlpha(1);` change the alpha value for entire row item.